# Are PLCC Chips/Sockets always the same pitch?

Tags: socket, through-hole

I'm hunting down a socket for a PLCC-84 chip and none of them mention pitch spacing.  Is that because PLCC is always the same spacing between pins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_carrier#Plastic_leaded_chip_carrier) article, yes:

"The PLCC utilizes a "J"-lead with pin spacings of 0.05" (1.27 mm)."

Which is confirmed by [this](http://www.aseglobal.com/en/Products/4-1-2-1.asp) page: the JEDEC standard for PLCC is "1.27mm (50mil) lead pitch".

I did a quick [search at JEDEC](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/results/taxonomy%3A3506) but only found specification for trays and tubes.

Comment: Also confirmed in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=cVHtBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA121). The next page[s] also gives the standard dimensions for the package[s] (square and rectangular).